# find and trim string endings in XML file

Tags: xml, linux, bash, sed, grep

Kinda new at scripting. I'm mostly a C# coder but...

I have a an XML file that contains a lot of nodes with repeated names but they all have ".txt" in the value

*Scan.xml*

```
<Parent Tags>
      ...
     <FileNameWithPath> Some/Path/That/has/file.extension.txt</FileNameWithPath>
      ...
 </Parent Tags>
      ...     
<Parent Tags>
      ...
     <FileNameWithPath> Some/NewPath/That/has/Newfile.DifferentExtension.txt</FileNameWithPath>
      ...
 </Parent Tags>
```

I'm trying to write a (bash) script in Linux to remove all the ".txt" substrings within the file.

testing things out, I have

`cat IpScan.xml | sed -ne '/<FileNameWithPath>/s#\s*<[^>]*>\s*##gp'`

but this only displays the value of the tag in the terminal.

I've also tried something like this

`grep -oP "<FileNameWithPath>(.*)</FileNameWithPath>" IpScan.xml | cut -d ">" -f 2 | cut -d "<" -f 1`

My thinking is to loop through each result of sed or grep and process the end of the string but then I don't know how to write the value back to the file. Also, I'm not sure grep or sed allows you to iterate (??)

My Question is this: How can I open the file, change the value of the element to remove the ".txt" string and save the file with the updated values?

I would prefer not to have to install another package as the Linux box I'm working on does not have network connectivity.

How can I

Comment: You can use inline-editing of the sed command: sed -i 's#.txt</FileNameWithPath>#</FileNameWithPath>#g' Scan.xml

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple `sed` command:

```
cat IpScan.xml | sed "s/\.txt</</"
```

#### explanation:

`s/\.txt</</` substitute ".txt<" with "<" once per line

Comment: Thank you! This was the only answer that didn't require me to use any other packages. Simple and very clean. I ended up using `sed` with the `-i` option to update the file; but other than that, it's just what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in the comments, it's generally a bad idea to use RegEx'es to manipulate XML files. But you can easily use XSLT for transforming parts of your XML. In the case of changing a single value, [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) provides a one line approach:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//Parent_Tags/FileNameWithPath" -x "normalize-space(concat(substring-before(.,'.txt'),substring-after(.,'.txt')))" input.xml
```

Here

- The `ed` option means, that the value is edited/changed
- The `-u` option specifies the XPath of the elements to be updated, like a `for-each` loop
- The `-x` option specifies the new value relative to the context node specified by the `-u` option. Here the string *before* `.txt` is concatenated to the string *after* `.txt`. The `normalize-space()` function removes leading and trailing space.

The updated XML is output to STDOUT and can, of course, be redirected to the new XML file.